# A model where the uniformity of the meager ideal is strictly below the almost disjointness number

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, cardinal-characteristics

I'm looking for a model satisfying the inequality described in the title. Recall that the *uniformity of the meager ideal*, denoted $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal M)$ (or $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal B)$) is the least size of a non meager set of reals and the *almost disjointness number*, denoted $\mathfrak{a}$ is the least size of an infinite, almost disjoint family. The reverse inequality, $\mathfrak{a} < \operatorname{non}(\mathcal M)$ holds in many well studied models, for example the random model. I seem to remember reading that $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal M) < \mathfrak{a}$ is also consistent though I can't seem to find the reference now. Therefore my question is:

Is it consistent that $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal M) < \mathfrak{a}$ if so, what model does this hold in?

As a remark, such a model is necessarily a model of $\mathfrak{b} < \mathfrak{a}$ which I do know to be consistent in several models (though none of the constructions are particularly easy compared to those for $\mathcal{a} < \operatorname{non}(\mathcal M)$). Therefore a related question is in which (if any) of the models for $\mathfrak{b} < \mathfrak{a}$ has $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal M)$ been computed?

I would be also extremely interested in a model of $\mathfrak{b} < \operatorname{non}(\mathcal M) < \mathfrak{a}$ though I wouldn't be surprised if this consistency was not known (please correct me if I'm mistaken!).

Thanks!

Comment: Shelah proved the consistency of both $\mathfrak{d} < \mathfrak{a}$ and the consistency $\mathfrak{u} < \mathfrak{a}$. (Same paper, but two different models.) I would not be surprised if one of these models had $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M) < \mathfrak{a}$ as well. If no one is able to answer your question outright, you might want to try computing $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal M)$ in these models, or try to modify the techniques from that paper.

Comment: https://shelah.logic.at/files/95437/700.pdf

Comment: @WillBrian Great thanks for the reference I will look into it!

Comment: This [paper](http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~vfischer/sba_alldifferent4.pdf) deals with your first question question.Your second question seems trickier, because using Hechler forcing in the template construction will likely yield $\text{add}(\mathcal{M})=\text{cof}(\mathcal{M})$.

Comment: @JohannesSchürz thanks! I'll check it out